# C# Moq: Cannot convert Moq.Mock<Arbiter> to Arbiter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface `Arbiter`

```
public interface Arbiter
{
    ContextData GetContextData();
}
```

I have a class that implements this interface.

```
public class ContextArbiter : Arbiter
{
   ContextData m_data;
    public CMBusContextArbiter()
        :
        base()
    {
       m_data = new ContextData();
    }

     public ContextData GetContextData()
     {
          return m_data;
     }
}
```

I have another class that uses this interface

```
public class SelectData 
{        
        private Arbiter m_Arbiter;
        public SelectData(Arbiter Arbiter)
        {            
            m_Arbiter = Arbiter;
        }

        public string RetrieveId()
        {
            return m_Arbiter.GetContextData().RouteId;            
        }
 }
```

Now I want to unit test this class

```
public class SelectDataTest : UnitTestBase
{
    private Mock<Arbiter> Arbiter;
    private SelectData SelectData;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        Arbiter= new Mock<Arbiter>();
        SelectData = new SelectData(Arbiter);
    }     
}
```

But it seems that I can't pass the mock object to the `SelectData` class. It shows

> Cannot convert Moq.Mock to Arbiter.

How can I get around this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Object` property of the `Mock<T>` class to access the mocked object.

```
//...

Arbiter = new Mock<Arbiter>();
SelectData = new SelectData(Arbiter.Object);

//...
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)